# Remove null values from JSON object using Jolt only. Keep rest of structure as is

Tags: json, jolt

Is there a way to just copy a JSON input as is and only remove null values?

I know the below can be used to get rid of the null values, but I still need to define a lot more for the JSON itself. Maybe there is a smart way to keep this jolt short.

```
{
  "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
  "spec": {
    "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nick, it depends on the input( you should provide a concrete one ) Indeed none of them will be more straightforward than this.